# how to get diff b/w two dates without using api?

Tags: java, date

i tried to get the following way but my guide instruct me to do without using api..
 can any one give it solution?

```
public class DateDifferenceExample{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    //get instance of Calendar objects
    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    //set two dates we want to know difference of
    cal1.set(2006, 12, 30);
    cal2.set(2007, 5, 3);

    long milis1 = cal1.getTimeInMillis();  
    long milis2 = cal2.getTimeInMillis();

    //difference in milliseconds
    long diff = milis2 - milis1;

    //difference in seconds
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;

    //difference in minutes
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);

    //difference in hours
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);

    //difference in days
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    System.out.println("Date difference in milliseconds: " + diff + " milliseconds.");     
    System.out.println("Date difference in seconds: " + diffSeconds + " seconds.");
    System.out.println("Date difference in minutes: " + diffMinutes + " minutes.");
    System.out.println("Date difference in hours: " + diffHours + " hours.");      
    System.out.println("Date difference in days: " + diffDays + " days.");

    }
}
```

Comment: Write the solution on a paper. then write a test in junit. Then write your code.  Your question does not really add any value for future visitor

Comment: @user3164190 - answer modified check now

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `compareTo()` method or the `before()` and `after()` methods to compare the dates. If you need the 'difference' then I recommend that you start comparing with years, then month and then days. That way you can get the exact difference between two dates.

> i don't want to use any methods

You **will** need to use methods to get the year, month and day. Have a look at: [Calendar.get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get)

**Example:**

```
Date1: 01 / 01 / 2014
Date2: 02 / 12 / 2015 

 Start with year. Subtract the years, use Math.abs() to get the absolute value.
 Then go for month. Subtract the months, use Math.abs() to get the absolute value.
 Then finally the day. Same story.

 The two dates are 1 year, 11 month and 1 day apart
```

*Note: The dates are in dd/mm/yyyy format*

Answer (score 0):

```
        Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal1.set(2006, 12, 30);
        cal2.set(2007, 5, 3);
        long startTime = cal1.getTimeInMillis();
        long endTime = cal2.getTimeInMillis();          

        long diff = endTime - startTime;
        long hoursRem=diff%(1000*60*60);
        diff=diff-hoursRem;
        long hours=diff/(1000*60*60);
        diff=diff+hoursRem;
        diff = diff - (hours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        long minRem=diff%(1000*60);
        diff=diff-minRem;
        long min=diff/(1000*60);
        diff=diff+minRem;
        diff = diff - (min * 60 * 1000);
        long seconds=diff/1000;
        System.out.println("hh = "+hours +"  min ="+min+" sec= "+seconds);
```

Comment: OP does not want methods. Implement the logic yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is OK. But it may be not exact for days because it does not take daylight savings.

Consider this

```
    GregorianCalendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 2, 29, 4, 0, 0);
    GregorianCalendar c2 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 2, 30, 4, 0, 0);
```

the difference in days is 1 full day. But this

```
    System.out.println(c2.getTimeInMillis() - c1.getTimeInMillis());
```

prints

```
82800000
```

that is difference in millis is 1 hour less, and your code for `diffDays` will produce 0